# Can whatsapp be integrated into a messaging hub?

Tags: messaging, whatsapp

Does the new whatsapp api support integration into a third party app where in you could send and receive the messages from the other app.The app would function more like a message hub.

Answer (score 0):

It can be integrated with other apps on iOS,

Please refer, http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: So you cannot have your whatsapp conversation appearing in a different app?